# Is there a VDI plugin for Skype For Business 2016? Is it needed?

Tags: lync, vdi, lync-2013, skype-for-business-2016

The [VDI plugin for Lync 2013](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj204683(v=ocs.15).aspx) allows using Lync 2013 (which automatically becomes SFB after some updates are installed) over a remote desktop connection without performance penalties, by offloading the audio/video processing to the RDP client.

But what to do if you are using Office 2016 and Skype For Business 2016 on your virtual desktops / terminal servers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the official Microsoft documentation [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj204683.aspx):

> This topic provides details on deploying the Microsoft Lync VDI
>   plug-in, which is only supported on Windows 7 and Windows 8 or Windows
>   Server 2008, and only supports Lync 2013 or Skype for Business 2015
>   clients.

Using the Lync VDI plugin should work with your Skype for Business 2015 clients. But Microsoft recommends using the new HDX RealTime Optimization Pack solution in new deployments.

Comment: ...for which you need Citrix. Of course.